# How do I use hardware performance counters in aarch64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, qemu, arm64

I am trying to time some generated assembly for ARM architectures. In this specific case the target is `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu`. I really want to count down to individual cycles, taking a few runs to get the minimum time taken and eliminate variance.

I do not have direct access to ARM hardware, so I am trying to run my code under QEMU.

For x86/x86_64 I am using the `rdtsc` and `rdtscp` instructions to return cycle counts.

For aarch64 I thought I could use

```
let clocks: u64;
asm!("mrs $0, pmccntr_el0" : "=r" (clocks) ::: "volatile");
```

But when I run

```
qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu myprogram
```

I am getting

```
qemu: uncaught target signal 4 (Illegal instruction) - core dumped
```

I thought maybe setting some bits in `pmcr_el0` register was required, but even reading from that using

```
let pmcr: u32;
asm!("mrs $0, pmcr_el0" : "=r" (pmcr) ::: "volatile");
```

gives the same `Illegal instruction` error.

It strikes me as though these are privileged instructions that need to be enabled for me - but I couldn't find documentation of how to do this with QEMU.

So is there a way to access the performance hardware in QEMU? Is there a way to count cycles in some other way? I really wanted it to match as closely to the x86 code as possible.

Comment: For x86/x86_64, your timing method returns *reference* cycles, not core clock cycles.  It doesn't account for turbo / power-saving clock variations at all.  This is a big deal on some CPUs, especially thermally-limited laptop CPUs where the max turbo is *much* higher than sustained, which is what the reference clock always ticks at.  I'd recommend using x86 perf counters, because you can count core clock cycles, cache misses, branch mispredicts, uops as well as instructions, and more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems that you forget to enable some bits at pmuserenr register.

Also, to use Performance Monitors Extension, please follow chapter D6 of [ARMv8 architecture reference manual](https://www.google.com/search?q=armv8%20architecture%20reference%20manual&oq=armv8%20architecture%20reference%20manual&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2.2513j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Please note that QEMU is not right tool for code profiling&optimizations.

QEMU first goal is emulation speed(>40 MIPS), and it provide some workable architecture profile reliable to OS developing. 
And then QEMU no need to support accurate ARMv8 performance monitors feature, current implementation is quite abstract and minimal: there is nothing except  inaccurate model of cycle counter PMCCNTR, and also there is no performance monitor events infrastructure at all.

You better use ordinary physical counter instead to produce time intervals:

```
mrs x0, cntpct_el0
```

To understand why cycle calculations on QEMU is useless, please note, that QEMU is a functional model, and it based on some assumptions:

1) All instructions performs sequentially one by one and consume equal time period each:

```
 1 guest instruction counter tick = 1 emulated nano second << icount_time_shift
```

icount_time_shift is specfied by "-icount" comand line option, it is 3 by default. Then 1 emulated guest instruction is 8 emulated nano-seconds.

Such strict conversion between instruction counter and nano-seconds is a key concept of QEMU dynamic guest code translation mechanism, which allows deterministic generation of translation blocks(TB): peripheral model, which is nano-second driven, binds to TB execution, which is instruction counter driven.

For example you execute 10 guest instructions as TB, and then advance peripheral clocks to 80 ns. Also peripheral can told TB execution loop that there is no any guest events expected for 800 ns, and it is possible to execute next 100 instructions as one TB.

2) Emulated nano-second is a basic clock unit and provide quantum of time at qemu, and all other guest counters scaled from it by some integer factor:

for example current QEMU implementation of ARM physical system counter(CNTPCT) hardcoded frequency is 62 MHz. Then

```
scale_factor = 10^9 / (62 *10^6) = 16, (division is integer)
```

i.e. QEMU do single increment of CNTPCT  per 16  increments of emulated nano-second. ARMv8 Generic Timer QEMU implementation based on that scale.

Also QEMU implements PMCR as a counter with some integer scale.

At QEMU you could manually count instructions at your guest program, multiple it to some constant, and i argue that it will be equal to the value, that your guest code try to calculate at runtime on QEMU.

And that results will be quite nothing to real code running on HW: You need to use one of proprietary performance simulators for target micro-architecture with caches model and pipeline, or test it at HW directly.